# how to remove the image plugin on ckeditor5 toolbar on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

how to remove the image plugin on ckeditor5 toolbar on react?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const Editor = ({onEditorStateChange, defaultValue}) => {
    const onChange = (event, editor ) => {
      const data = editor.getData();
      console.log(  data  );
      onEditorStateChange(data)
    };

    const onBlur = (event, editor) => {
      console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
    };

    const onFocus = (event, editor) => {
      console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
    };

    const onInit = (editor) => {
      // editor
      // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
      console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
    };

    return (
        <div className="editor">
            {/* <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2> */}
            <CKEditor
                editor={ClassicEditor}
                data={defaultValue}
                onInit={onInit}
                onChange={onChange}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onFocus={onFocus}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Editor;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a `config` property to the `CKEditor` component and pass in an array of strings to the `removePlugins` prop.

```
  <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          config={{
            removePlugins: ['Image', 'ImageCaption', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageUpload', 'MediaEmbed']
          }}
          data={defaultValue}
          onChange={onChange}
        >
        </CKEditor>
```

Here is more information on the CKEditor React component:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html#component-properties

Here is a link to the configuration options
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html

Here is a list of the default plugins with the ClassicEditor:

- Essentials
- CKFinderUploadAdapter
- Autoformat
- Bold
- Italic
- BlockQuote
- CKFinder
- EasyImage
- Heading
- Image
- ImageCaption
- ImageStyle
- ImageToolbar
- ImageUpload
- Indent
- Link
- List
- MediaEmbed
- Paragraph
- PasteFromOffice
- Table
- TableToolbar
- TextTransformation

Answer (score 1):

> My React solution

In my React component below only worked to remove Image and Media icons

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    config={{
        removePlugins: ["EasyImage","ImageUpload","MediaEmbed"]
    }}
    data={form.description}
    onChange={(event, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        setForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, description: data }))
        // console.log({ event, editor, data });
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the image plugin with this config :

```
{
  removePlugins: ['ImageInsert', 'ImageUpload'],
}
```